# Allowing users to implement their own methods. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, code-injection

I'm not sure if this is possible but I wanted to ask. I wrote a program that generates c# classes from database tables. It would be real nice to allow a user to write his own method that would meet the format of his needs because what I define might be overkill or underkill for someone. I realize there are a lot of variables involved but that is secondary; I'm sure that implementing an interface would be a sure-fire way to get around some potential pitfalls ( I'm only thinking out loud of course )

If this is possible, where should I start looking to learn what I need to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reflection and dynamic Assembly loading. Search for these.

Comment: You will want to take a look at [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx). It enables you to implement a "Plug In" architecture really easily.

Comment: Bold strategy Cotton, lets see if it works out for em'!

Comment: Thanks MarcinJuraszek. I'm going to search for those now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and you can make it secure with CodeAccessSecurity. However it isn't easy:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113169/C-As-A-Scripting-Language-In-Your-NET-Applications